# Is there a native approach to trigger an event for event-handlers attached after event had been fired?

Tags: javascript

If you are using native Events api and not rolling your own out then how can you make sure that event handlers who attach to an event get that event even if an event had already fired. Assume this event only fires once.

Example...you load data from some api. You UI attaches an event to 'dataLoaded' usually fetching data takes time and event handlers get attached before fetching completes. However, sometimes data is too small and fetching requests takes almost no time and UI being attaches the event listener after the fetching was done, and thus missed it.

This is just an example not an actual use case..

I want to be able to provide events for my code where if someone attaches an event then they get that event.

Another way to think about this is you ask someone to tell me when the train arrives, and he goes back and the train was already there but he doesn't tell you. When you ask him why didn't he say anything, he replies well the train was already here, technically no train arrived after me.

=============

another way to phrase this question....

You have pub/sub system. You want certain messages to be delivered even if someone subscribed after the message was published on certain channel.

Answer (score 2):

Promises make for handy containers of async data. You can call `.then()` as many times as you want on them and will always be guaranteed to receive the resolved data.

For example

```js
// Example async function
function getData() {
  const data = { items: [1,2,3] }
  // Takes 200ms to resolve data
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 200, data))
}

// Store the promise
const dataLoaded = getData()

// Here's an early listener, attached before resolving
dataLoaded.then(data => {
  console.log("Early listener got:", data.items)
})

// Wait and add another listener well after the data has resolved
setTimeout(() => {
  dataLoaded.then(data => {
    console.log("Late listener got:", data.items)
  })
}, 1000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: `then` definitely has that behavior.